# Scanner looping through integers from file in certain manner

Tags: java

I just had a quick question regarding on how best to do this in one iteration of a loop.

If I initialize a scanner from the following text file...

```
x1 2 3 -1 x2 2 x3 4 x4 5 -1
```

I use the following code:

```
String name;
int value;
ArrayList<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    name = scanner.next();
    //Over here, I'm trying to assign value to be 2 and 4 (only for x2 and x3),     not 2, 3, or 5 because it's followed by a -1
    value = 2 and 4
    tempList.add(value);
}
```

So in my iteration, if a name is followed by a number/multiple numbers which end with a -1, do nothing, but if a name is followed by a number then set value = number

Would this require multiple passes through the file to know what strings end with a -1 number?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ I want to set value = 2 and 4 because the list of integers following the string doesn't end with -1. Eventually i'll add it to an arraylist, but for the time being just set value = 2 and 4.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ yes, because it's only followed by 1 number and doesn't end with -1, I edited it to make it more clear

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ thank you.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ in this example it's only going to be x2 and x3, but if I'm given a different sample set, lets say x1 3 x2 3 x3 3 x4 5 6 -1 x5 5 -1, then i'm only using x1, x2, and x3 because the following numbers don't end in -1

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ thank you, because variables names can change depending on the file given.

Comment: Please see the updated answer - the old one would omit the last value if it wasn't `-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it

```
    String s = " x1 2 3 -1 x2 2 x3 4 x4 5 -1 lastone 4";

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);

    String currentName = null;
    int currentNumber = -1;

    while (sc.hasNext()) {

        String token = sc.next();

        if (token.matches("-?\\d+")) {
            currentNumber = Integer.parseInt(token);
        } else {
            if (currentName != null && currentNumber > -1) {
                System.out.println(currentName + " = " + currentNumber);
            }
            currentName = token;
            currentNumber = -1;
        }
    }

    if (currentName != null && currentNumber > -1) {
        System.out.println(currentName + " = " + currentNumber);
    }
```

Output:

```
x2 = 2
x3 = 4
lastone = 4
```

**EDIT**: correction (printing the last pair if present)